# Put Bootstrap modal label to the left of the control

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I’m building a modal and need to put labels not on top of the input/select controls as they would be placed by default but to the left of the control. [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/juZSlRnzZUp13Hflj65i?p=preview). Please click the icon under the Outlet header to see the modal.

How do I put a label to the left of a control so both are evenly placed on the same line? The way I did this (with `<h4>` tags) feels like not the Bootstrap way to me. Do I need to use labels and not `<h4>`?

There will 2 labels and 2 controls per line as shown on Plunker.
Also how do I control the font size of the labels within the modal?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

    <title>F Trace</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="../../assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">



    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

        <!-- Modal Outlet Access-->
        <div class="modal fade adduser" id="outletaccess" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Доступ к объекту</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class='form-group form-group-sm'>
                            <div class='row'>
                                <div class='col-xs-12'>
                                    <h4>User name / outlet name</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='form-group form-group-sm'>
                            <div class='row'>
                                <div class='col-xs-12'>
                                    <h4><i class="fa fa-filter fa-2x"></i>Sort</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='form-group form-group-sm'>
                            <div class='row'>
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <h4>Region</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <div class='form-group'>
                                        <select class='form-control'>
                                            <option>all</option>
                                            <option>all</option>
                                            <option>all</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <h4>Outlet class:</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <div class='form-group'>
                                        <select class='form-control'>
                                            <option>Store</option>
                                            <option>Store</option>
                                            <option>Store</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='form-group form-group-sm'>
                            <div class='row'>
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <h4>Area:</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <div class='form-group'>
                                        <select class='form-control'>
                                            <option>all</option>
                                            <option>all</option>
                                            <option>all</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <h4>Outlet type:</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <div class='form-group'>
                                        <select class='form-control'>
                                            <option>type</option>
                                            <option>type</option>
                                            <option>type</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='form-group form-group-sm'>
                            <div class='row'>
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <h4>City:</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <div class='form-group'>
                                        <select class='form-control'>
                                            <option>city</option>
                                            <option>city</option>
                                            <option>city</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <h4>Company:</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <div class='form-group'>
                                        <select class='form-control'>
                                            <option>all</option>
                                            <option>all</option>
                                            <option>all</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Discard</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <section id='top5'>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-md-12 settings'>
                        <table class="table text-center custom-table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th width="20%">Name</th>
                                    <th width="3%">Rep</th>
                                    <th width="13%">Phone</th>
                                    <th width="10%">E-mail</th>
                                    <th width="10%">Level</th>
                                    <th width="12%"><div>Access to</div><div class='controls'><i class="fa fa-bolt"></i><i class="fa fa-tint"></i><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i><i class="fa fa-yelp"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o"></i><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i></div></th>
                                    <th width="5%">Outlet</th>
                                    <th width="5%">Edit</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>John Doe</td>
                                    <td class="vert-align"><input type='checkbox'></input></td>
                                    <td>777 123 4455</td>
                                    <td>contact@company.com</td>
                                    <td>Admin</td>
                                    <td class="vert-align checkboxes"><input type='checkbox'></input><input type='checkbox'></input><input type='checkbox'></input><input type='checkbox'></input><input type='checkbox'></input><input type='checkbox'></input></td>
                                    <td class="vert-align"><i data-toggle="modal" data-target="#outletaccess" class="fa fa-industry"></td>
                                    <td class="vert-align"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First you add to alert with `col-xs-3` and `col-xs-9`, one line equal `col-xs-12` instead of four `col-xs-3`. Then you have to remove the `h4` tags to `label` tag instead and set a `font-size` to the `.form-group label` css class.

Comment: Could you please put lines of code here so I could get it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the select has bootstrap styles as follows

```css
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

So you need to change that to

```css
.form-control {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

And put label to the same div as the select. Surely it's better to use labels than h4.

Than style it how you need it to look good - this is the core idea.
Here is your [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7Agv7TZlpCyXoT3NfkCd?p=preview) forked

Comment: Looks neat. I'll take another look at your solution tomorrow. It's late at night here. Thank you.

Comment: I tag the answer as accepted. How do I make the dropdown menus to fill all the space right to the label?